# What advantages do we find when using a mixed model for nested data instead of multiple regression?

Tags: mixed-model, multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis, nested-data

I'm learning about mixed models because in my job we are trying to advise researchers about statistical questions they might have. So long I've been learning using the demidenko [mixed model book](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Mixed+Models:+Theory+and+Applications+with+R,+2nd+Edition-p-9781118091579) and the [datacamp course on mixed models.](https://app.datacamp.com/learn/courses/hierarchical-and-mixed-effects-models-in-r). The thing is, I want to explain to my boss why should we use mixed models for nested data because much of our data comes from observations where patients give multiple data points over time. I've collected these points but I would like some help if possible.

• An independence of the predictor variables is achieved.

• Limitations related to subgroups or individuals are avoided.

• Work is being done to take [Simpson's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox) into account.

• It is useful for correlated data and with interactions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The primary reason why you want to use mixed models for repeated measurement data is that measurements taken on the same patient are correlated. Standard statistical regression models, such as linear regression and generalized linear models, are designed to work with independent observations and are, therefore, inappropriate for correlated data.

If you use a statistical analysis technique that wrongly ignores these correlations, you may obtain incorrect inferences (i.e., p-values). An example of this is given in my [slides (Section 1.2)](https://www.drizopoulos.com/courses/EMC/CE08.pdf). If you also have missing data in your repeated measurement outcome (e.g., because some patients drop out from the study), ignoring these correlations may result in biased estimated coefficients.

Comment: Great answer! Do you have more material like those slides you just shared? It looks like a great source of knowledge.

Comment: Jorge, you can check out University of Bristol's Centre for multilevel modelling, they have a good set of resources.